# I am having issues while decryption using RNCryptor Library

Tags: swift, rncryptor

While decrypting I get the error : The operation couldnot be performed RNCryptorError 1
I dont understand what I am doing wrong. Here is my block of code
[image]

Answer (score 1):

*For anyone who might search here: this is a duplicate of [RNCryptor#174](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor/issues/174), and you may want to read there as well.*

Please just post code into the question rather than a screenshot. I can't compile a screenshot, and they're very hard to read.

Error 1 is an HMAC error. Either your data is corrupted or your password is incorrect.

Note that NSException never makes sense in Swift. Switch can't catch them. They only make sense in ObjC if you're going to crash the program shortly after. They're not memory-safe in ObjC. You meant to use Swift's throw and ErrorType, which are unrelated to raise or NSException.